# Fact about measurable functions defined on $\sigma$-finite measure spaces.

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

$\bf{\text{Background:}}$

Let $(\Omega,\Sigma,\mu)$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure space, and $X$ be a Banach space.

A function $f:\Omega\to X$ is simple if it assumes only finitely many values.  That is, there exists subsets $E_{1}, ... , E_{n}$ of $\Omega$ and scalars $x_{1}, ... , x_{n}\in X$ such that $f = \sum_{i=1}^{n}\chi_{E_{i}}x_{i}$.

If the sets $E_{i}$ can be chosen from $\Sigma$, then $f$ is $\mu$-measurable simple.

A function $f:\Omega\to X$ is measurable if it is the limit of a sequence of $\mu$-measurable simple functions (almost everywhere).

---

$\bf{\text{Problem Statement:}}$

A function $f:\Omega\to X$ is measurable $\Leftrightarrow$ $\chi_{E}f$ is measurable for all $E\in \Sigma$ such that $\mu(E) < \infty$.

---

$\bf{\text{Partial Solution:}}$

The $(\Rightarrow)$ direction is easy.  Write $f = \lim_{n\to\infty}f_{n}$ for $\mu$-measurable simple $f_{n}$.  Then $\chi_{E}f_{n}$ is $\mu$-measurable simple and converges $\chi_{E}f$ almost everywhere.

The $(\Leftarrow)$ direction is giving me problems.  I thought at first to let (as in the definition of $\sigma$-finite) $(E_{n})_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence in $\Sigma$ such that $\mu(E_{n}) < \infty$ and $\Omega = \cup_{n=1}^{\infty}E_{n}$, and defining 
$F_{n} = \cup_{j=1}^{n}E_{j}$.  Then for each $n\geq 1$, take a sequence $(g^{n}_{m})_{m=1}^{\infty}$ of $\mu$-measurable simple functions which converges to $\chi_{F_{n}}f$, by assumption.  I thought I might be able to show that $g_{n}^{n}\to f$ almost everywhere, but I couldn't figure out the trick.  My idea is below.

I claim that $\{\lambda\in \Omega : g^{n}_{n}(\lambda)\not\to f(\lambda)\}\subset\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\{\lambda\in\Omega : g^{n}_{m}(\lambda)\not\to \chi_{F_{n}}(\lambda)f(\lambda)\}$, the latter set being $\mu$-measure $0$.

Is am I on the right track?  I can't prove my claim.

Comment: Isn't it enough to observe that $f = f \chi_\Omega$?

Comment: That seems to work.  But then $\sigma$-finiteness has not been used?

Comment: Or does $\sigma$-finiteness imply that $\Omega$ is measurable?

Comment: The fact that $\Sigma$ is a $\sigma-$ algebra implies that $\Omega$ is measurable (it's part of the definition).  This result is true for any measurable map between measure spaces.

Comment: Maybe the problem statement should be: $f$ is measurable iff $\chi_Ef$ is measurable for each $E\in\Sigma$ *such that* $\mu(E)<\infty$? Then $\sigma-finitness is really needed.

Comment: You are correct Etienne, sorry for the omission.

Comment: Is it a diagonal argument like the one I am trying to apply?  I still am stuck in the same place.

Comment: Let $A_n = F_n \setminus F_{n-1}$. Then $\mu(A_n) < \infty$, $\Omega = \bigcup A_n$, and the $A_n$ are disjoint. For each $n$, let $(g_k^n)_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ a sequence of simple functions converging (a.e.) to $f\chi_{A_n}$ vanishing outside $A_n$. Let $f_m = \sum_{n=1}^m g_m^n$.

Comment: Thanks!  This has been bugging me for 2 days now. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A diagonalization argument would work, we just need to take care how to approximate our functions. For ease of notation, define
$$\begin{align}H_1 &= F_1\\
H_{n+1} &= F_{n+1}\setminus F_n\end{align}$$
so that the $H_n$'s are pairwise disjoint and $\bigcup_{k=1}^n H_k = F_n$.

For all $n\geq 1$ we can take measurable simple functions $\{g^{(n)}_m\}_{m\geq 1}$ such that $g^{(n)}_m\mathop{\longrightarrow}_{m\to\infty} f^{(n)} := \chi_{H_n}f$. W.l.o.g. we can assume that $g^{(n)}_m$ is supported in $H_n$.

Define the functions
$$h_n := \sum_{k=1}^n g^{(k)}_n.$$
Clearly, for all $n\geq 1$ we have $\chi_{F_n}h_m\mathop{\longrightarrow}_{m\to\infty} \sum_{k=1}^n f^{(k)}=\chi_{F_n} f$ almost everywhere (since for every sufficiently large $m$ we have $\chi_{F_n}h_m = \sum_{k=1}^n g^{(k)}_m$), and since $\Omega=\bigcup F_n$ we're done.

Comment: @DanielFischer, apologies for missing your comment.

Comment: I tried to skip your technique of calculating the limit of $\chi_{F_{n}}h_{m}$ for $m\to\infty$, and tried to take $h_{m}$'s limit directly and see why you needed to restrict.

Thanks for the details!