# Extend Pettis's measurability theorem to $\sigma$-finite measure spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, banach-spaces, measurable-functions

I'm reading Pettis's measurability theorem from Diestel-Uhl's *Vector Measures*.

---

The basis for this material is a measure space $(\Omega, \Sigma, \mu)$  and a Banach space $X$.

**Definition 1.** A function $f: \Omega \rightarrow X$ is called **$\mu$-simple** if there exist $x_1, \ldots, x_n \in X$ and $E_1, \ldots, E_n \in \sum$ such that $\mu(E_i) < \infty$ for all $i=1, \ldots, n$, and $f=\sum_{i=1}^n x_i \chi_{E_i}$, where $1_{E_i}(\omega)=1$ if $\omega \in E_i$ and $1_{E_i}(\omega)=0$ if $\omega \notin E_i$. A function $f: \Omega \rightarrow X$ is called **$\mu$-measurable** if there exists a sequence of simple functions $\left(f_n\right)$ with $\lim _n\left\|f_n-f\right\|=0$ $\mu$-almost everywhere. A function $f: \Omega \rightarrow X$ is called **weakly $\mu$-measurable** if for each $x^* \in X^*$ the numerical function $x^* \circ f$ is $\mu$-measurable.

**Theorem 2** (Pettis's measurability theorem) Let $(\Omega, \Sigma, \mu)$ be **finite**. A function $f: \Omega \rightarrow X$ is $\mu$-measurable if and only if

- (i) $f$ is $\mu$-essentially separably valued, i.e., there exists $E \in \Sigma$ with $\mu(E)=0$ and such that $f(\Omega \backslash E)$ is a (norm) separable subset of $X$, and
- (ii) $f$ is weakly $\mu$-measurable.

---

The authors assume that the measure space is finite. I'm trying to see if this theorem holds for $\sigma$-finite measure spaces, i.e.,

> **Conjecture:** Let $(\Omega, \Sigma, \mu)$ be **$\sigma$-finite**. A function $f: \Omega \rightarrow X$ is $\mu$-measurable if and only if
>
> - (i) $f$ is $\mu$-essentially separably valued, i.e., there exists $E \in \Sigma$ with $\mu(E)=0$ and such that $f(\Omega \backslash E)$ is a (norm) separable subset of $X$, and
> - (ii) $f$ is weakly $\mu$-measurable.

Could you confirm if the conjecture is true and if my below proof is valid?

**My attempt:** We have 2 lemmas, i.e.,

> [Lemma 1:](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4507762/generalize-a-theorem-about-the-mu-measurability-of-a-mu-a-e-limit-of-a-se) Assume $(\Omega, \Sigma, \mu)$ is $\sigma$-finite and **not** necessarily complete. Let $(f_n)$ be sequence of $\mu$-measurable functions, and $f \in X^\Omega$ the $\mu$-a.e. limit of $(f_n)$. Then $f$ is also $\mu$-measurable.
>
> [Lemma 2:](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/484303/fact-about-measurable-functions-defined-on-sigma-finite-measure-spaces) A function $f:\Omega\to X$ is $\mu$-measurable if and only if $1_Ef$ is $\mu$-measurable for all $E\in \Sigma$ such that $\mu(E) < \infty$.

Notice that the restriction of a $\mu$-measurable function to a measurable subset is also $\mu$-measurable.

- Assume $f$ is $\mu$-measurable.

Because $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite, there is a measurable partition $(E_n) \subset \Sigma$ of $\Omega$ such that $\mu(E_n) < \infty$ for all $n$.

By **Lemma 2**, $1_{E_n} f$ is $\mu$-measurable for all $n$. Notice that $1_{E_n} f$ is supported on $E_n$ which has finite $\mu$-measure. By **Theorem 2**, $1_{E_n} f$ is $\mu$-essentially separably valued and weakly $\mu$-measurable. Clearly, $f$ is $\mu$-essentially separably valued. Let $x^* \in X^*$. We have the point-wise convergence
$$
x^* \circ f =   x^* \circ \left(\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^n 1_{E_i} f\right) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^n x^* \circ (1_{E_i} f).
$$

Because $x^* \circ (1_{E_n} f)$ is $\mu$-measurable for all $i \ge 1$, we have $\sum_{i=1}^n x^* \circ (1_{E_i} f)$ is also $\mu$-measurable. By **Lemma 1**, $x^* \circ f$ is $\mu$-measurable and thus $f$ is weakly $\mu$-measurable.

- Assume $f$ is $\mu$-essentially separably valued and weakly $\mu$-measurable.

Let $E \in \Sigma$ such that $\mu(E) < \infty$. Then $1_E f$ is $\mu$-essentially separably valued and weakly $\mu$-measurable. Notice that $1_{E} f$ is supported on $E$ which has finite $\mu$-measure. Then by **Theorem 2**, $1_E f$ is $\mu$-measurable. Then by **Lemma 2**, $f$ is $\mu$-measurable. This completes the proof.