# A proof of the polar decomposition of a complex measure

Tags: measure-theory, radon-nikodym

Let $(X, \mathcal X)$ be a measurable space. Let $\mu$ be a [complex measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_measure) on $X$ and $|\mu|$ its [variation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_measure#Variation_of_a_complex_measure_and_polar_decomposition). Then $|\mu|$ is a non-negative finite measure. By definition, $|\mu(B)| \le |\mu| (B)$ for all $B \in \mathcal X$, so $\mu \ll |\mu|$. By [Radon-Nikodym](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon%E2%80%93Nikodym_theorem#Extension_to_signed_or_complex_measures) for complex measures, there is a measurable $f:X \to \mathbb C$ such that
$$
\mu (B) = \int_B f \mathrm d |\mu| \quad \forall B \in \mathcal X.
$$

Now I would like the prove the [polar decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_measure#Variation_of_a_complex_measure_and_polar_decomposition) of $\mu$, i.e.,

> **Theorem:** $|f(x)|=1$ for $|\mu|$-a.e. $x \in X$.

Could you have a check on my attempt?

---

**Proof:** For $B \in \mathcal X$, let $\Pi(B)$ be the collection of all finite measurable partitions of $B$. For $B \in \mathcal X$, we have
$$
\begin{align}
|\mu| (B) &= \sup \bigg  \{ \sum_{i=1}^m |\mu (B_i)| : (B_i)_{i=1}^m \in \Pi(B) \bigg\} \\
&= \sup \bigg  \{ \sum_{i=1}^m \left | \int_{B_i} f \mathrm d |\mu|  \right | : (B_i)_{i=1}^m \in \Pi(B) \bigg\} \\
&\le \sup \bigg  \{ \sum_{i=1}^m \int_{B_i} |f| \mathrm d |\mu| : (B_i)_{i=1}^m \in \Pi(B) \bigg\} \\
&= \int_B |f| \mathrm d |\mu|.
\end{align}
$$

This implies
$$
\int_B \mathrm d |\mu| \le \int_B |f| \mathrm d |\mu| \quad \forall B \in \mathcal X,
$$
and thus $|f(x)| \ge 1$ for $|\mu|$-a.e. $x \in X$. For the reverse inequality, we need the following lemma, i.e.,

> [Lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4572793/if-left-frac1-mua-int-a-f-mathrm-d-mu-right-in-g-for-all-a) Let $(X, \mathcal F, \mu)$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure space and $(E, |\cdot|_E)$ a Banach space. Here we use the [Bochner integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4298588/dominated-convergence-theorem-for-banach-space). Let $f \in L_1(X, \mu, E)$, $\mathcal A := \{A \in \mathcal F :  \mu(A) \in (0, \infty)\}$, and
> $$
> \varphi(A) := \frac{1}{\mu(A)} \int_A f \mathrm d \mu \quad \forall A \in \mathcal A.
> $$
> Let $G$ be a non-empty closed subset of $\mathbb R$. If $|\varphi (A)|_E \in G$ for all $A \in \mathcal A$ then $|f(x)|_E \in G$ for almost all $x \in X$.

Notice that we have $|\mu(B)| \le |\mu| (B)$ and thus
$$
\left | \frac{1}{|\mu| (B)}\int_B f \mathrm d |\mu| \right | \le 1
$$
for all $B \in \mathcal X$ such that $|\mu|(B) \neq 0$. By our **Lemma**, $|f(x)| \le 1$ for $|\mu|$-a.e. $x \in X$. This completes the proof.