# A generalization of Theorem 1.40 in Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, metric-spaces, banach-spaces, bochner-spaces

Let $(X, \mathcal F, \mu)$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure space and $(E, |\cdot|)$ a Banach space. Here we use the [Bochner integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4298588/dominated-convergence-theorem-for-banach-space). Then we have *Theorem 1.40* in Rudin's *Real and Complex Analysis*, i.e.,

> [Theorem 1.40](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4547605/generalize-theorem-1-40-in-rudins-real-and-complex-analysis) Let $f \in L_1(X, \mu, E)$ and $F$ be a non-empty closed subset of $E$. If
> $$
> \varphi(A) :=\frac{1}{\mu(A)} \int_A f \mathrm d \mu \in F \quad \forall A \in \mathcal F \text{ s.t. } \mu(A) \in (0, \infty),
> $$
> then $f(x) \in F$ for $\mu$-a.e. $x \in X$.

I would like to strengthen above theorem when $X$ is given more structure, i.e.,

> **Proposition** Let $X$ be a metric space, $\tau$ its metric topology, $\mathcal F$ its Borel $\sigma$-algebra, and $\mathcal C$ the collection of all closed subsets of $X$. **Theorem 1.40** still holds true if we restrict the test sets $A \in \mathcal F$ to those $A \in \tau$ (or to those $A \in \mathcal C$).

Could you confirm if my below attempt is fine?

---

**Proof** Assume that $\varphi (A) \in F$ for every $O \in \tau$ with $\mu(O) \in (0, \infty)$. Fix $A \in \mathcal F$ with $\mu(A) \in (0, \infty)$. Because $\mu$ is outer regular, there is a sequence $(O_n) \subset \tau$ such that $A \subset O_{n+1}\subset O_n$ and that $\lim_n \mu(O_n) = \mu(A)$. Clearly, $\frac{1}{\mu(O_n)} \to \frac{1}{\mu(A)}$. Also, $1_{O_n} f \to 1_A f$ $\mu$-a.e. By [dominated convergence theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4298588/dominated-convergence-theorem-for-banach-space), $\int_{O_n} f \mathrm d \mu \to  \int_A f \mathrm d \mu$. As such,
$$
\varphi (O_n) \to \varphi (A).
$$

Because $\varphi (O_n) \in F$ for all $n$ and $F$ is closed, we get $\varphi (A) \in F$. The claim then follows from **Theorem 1.40**.  $\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$

Comment: Seems good! ${}$